# Forever moving ball

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-physics

How do I create a body [A ball Body] that will bounce around the screen, never losing or gaining speed, regardless of what it hits in cocos2d-box2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set restitution of the fixture to 1, and friction to 0.

Box2D manual says:

> Restitution is used to make objects bounce. The restitution value is usually set to be between 0 and 1. Consider dropping a ball on a table. <...> A value of one means the ball's velocity will be exactly reflected. This is called a perfectly elastic collision.
>
> A friction value of 0 turns off friction

Without friction and with perfectly elastic collision your ball will bounce around the screen, never losing or gaining speed **in a static environment**. If environment is not static, then colliding with moving object will change speed of the ball.

To solve this problem, I suggest next trick. Set contact listener, and in PostSolve method correct speed of you ball like this:

```
void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse)
{  
   if(contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody() == YOUR_BALL_BODY ||
      contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody() == YOUR_BALL_BODY)
   {
       float speed = YOUR_BALL_BODY->GetLinearVelocity().Length();
       float koef = YOUR_NEEDED_SPEED / speed;
       YOUR_BALL_BODY->SetLinearVelocity(koef * YOUR_BALL_BODY->GetLinearVelocity());
   }
}
```

How to set contact listener see [there](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Periodically multiply the velocity of the body by the scalar quantity `t/v.length` where t is target velocity.

The other answer is likely a bit more complex than what you need.